# Is there a way to allocate memory from a specific memory location?

Tags: c++, memory

let me explain this with an example :
imagine we want to resize an array of objects that were allocated dynamically before ...
so we have a solution like this :

creating a new array with new size and trying to copy old array to this one and trying to deallocate old array ...

but what i want is to check the memory right after the array for free space and if it's exist allocating the memory for my array and than preventing from memory overhead !on the other hand , if we don't have enough memory for our new array and old array at the same time ,we cannot resize it !

Is there a way to allocate memory from a specific memory location?

Comment: Your example would be better with some code, even pseudocode. As it stands it sounds like you simply want to use `std::vector`.

Comment: no i want to do it by my own not with c++ standard classes like vector

Comment: Then show how you would expect something like that to work in code, as I mentioned it's quite hard to understand what you're asking with text alone.

Comment: ok look at this :

bool resize(stuff *input){
if(Is_memory_free(from:input.last(), to:input.last() + sizeof(one block of input)))
      void *newmemory = allocate_memory(from:input.last(), to:input.last() + sizeof(one block of input))
      attach_to_array(old_memory:input, new__memory:newmemory)
else
      return false

return true
}

Comment: See realloc and the below mentioned placement new

Comment: Before trying to reallocate an array this way you need to check whether memory just after the array is free. And for that you need to write your own memory allocation library, because standard C++ allocation routines won't let you do that

Answer (score 2):

You probably need `placement new`, it actually "places/constructs" your object in a specific memory address. Placement new does **not** allocate memory and you should call the destructor manually for the object. have the following syntax

```
char memory[sizeof(Fred)];   // allocate a block of memory with sizeof(Fred)  
void* place = memory;          
Fred* f = new(place) Fred();
// The pointers f and place will be equal 

f->~Fred(); // explicitly delete the object *not* the memory block.
```

The guide line is don't use Placement new unless you know what you are doing. For example specialized memory allocators where you are sure that will enhance performance. For example in a game a memory pool is often created where many objects are created and deleted continuously, you can allocate a specific size memory block and then construct and delete objects (reuse memory blocks).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want the [placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) operator. Read also [operator new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) documentation, [C++ memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), and consider having specialized [Allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator)

Answer (score 0):

This one triggered memories of my interview when having asked this question my answer was "No way".

Indeed there are many uses of placement new one of which is to place an object at a particular location in memory.

```
#include <new>        // >>>>>>>>>Must #include this to use "placement new"
#include "abc.h"     // Declaration of class Abc.

void someCode()
{
  char memory[sizeof(Abc)];     
  void* place = memory;          

  Abc* f = new(place) Abc();   
  // The pointers f and place will be equal  <<<< CAUTION OVER HERE

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid arrays moving, and the only good reason I can think of is the array needs lockless multithreaded access to it, you may be better off allocating it in the first place with `mmap` reserving address space that will always be enough. Assuming youre on a 64bit os, address space is virtually an infinite supply.
`malloc` may work on linux depending on your overcommit settings, new cant be used doing this since the consructors will access the data and use up all your memory.

Comment: actually, `::operator new(num_bytes)` would work perfectly fine for memory allocation and you wouldn't have to include `<cstdlib>` to use it.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode this is not true on all platforms. Solaris and friends will never overcommit with new or malloc, linux may or may not depending on overcommit settings. Also, mmaped memory is guaranteed to be 0s when read, newed or malloced this is undefined behaviour - big no no. Also, if you new this, you cant use constructors if you are trying to overcommit, or the memory will be written.

Comment: I don't think I read your answer correctly over the first time. You're right; `new` would probably never overcommit and I wouldn't rely on `malloc` to either.